# Show values from multiple json objects using handlebars.js

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, loops, handlebars.js

I'm trying to show data from two separate ajax calls.

I've started experimenting with handlebars.js and managed to show data but only from one call. How can I refactor my code to show data from the second call as well?

**HTML:**

```
<header>
  <img id="twitch-logo" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c6/Twitch_logo_%28wordmark_only%29.svg">
</header>

<div id="result-placeholder"></div>
<script type="text/handlebars-template" id="handlebars-template"> 
  {{#each this}}
  <div class="result-wrapper">
    <a href="{{channel.url}}" target="_blank">
      <div><img src="{{channel.logo}}" class="result-logo"></div>
      <div class="result-name">User: {{channel.display_name}}</div>
      <div class="result-game">Currently streaming: {{channel.game}}</div>
    </a>
  </div>
  {{/each}}
</script>
```

**JS:**

```
var streamers = ['monstercat', 'lirik'];

function getStream(name) {
  return $.ajax('https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/' + name + '?callback=?', { dataType: 'JSON' });
}

function displayStream(data) {
  var $placeHolder = $("#result-placeholder");
  var handlebarsTemplate = $("#handlebars-template").html();
  var templateCompile = Handlebars.compile(handlebarsTemplate);
  $placeHolder.html(templateCompile(data)); 
}

streamers.map(function(element) {
  getStream(element)
    .then(displayStream);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it looks like you are using jQuery to perform the http fetch of your streams. I suggest looking at the jQuery API, and use for instance jQuery.when( deferreds ) to combine async fetch of 2 or more resources:

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/